# t-sql to get the create table script in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to retreive the create table script in t-sql. I tried the `select into DBLocal.dbo.TableX from DBProduction.dbo.TablesX where 1=2` query but it does not create all constraints, keys and indexes.

Thank you

Comment: [How to generate scripts to recreate table using SQL Server Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521085/how-to-generate-scripts-to-recreate-table-using-sql-server-management-studio#13521141)

Comment: thank you lad2025. I already know this solution. I am looking for a script that can give me also the create index statement. Maybe this can be done by joining the index dmv